# HashMap of ArrayList as the value initialization

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I am trying to make a `HashMap` that takes the value as a `List<Pack>` where `Pack` is an object that I created, then adds Packs to this list if the condition is true.

Now I get errors even though the condition is true, and I think I did not initialize it correctly can someone tell me where the problem is?

```
static HashMap<Long, List<Pack>> ackPkts = new HashMap<Long, List<Pack>>();

static HashMap<Long, List<Pack>> dataPkts = new HashMap<Long, List<Pack>>();

static List<Pack> pktList = new ArrayList<Pack>();

if((msg.getPayloadLength()) == 0 && (msg.isSYN()) == false && (msg.isACK()) == true){ 

    Pack pack = new Pack(msg.getAck(), msg.sackPresent(), captureTime, srcIP, destIP, msg.isSYN());

    (ackPkts.get(msg.getAck())).add(pack);

} else { 

    Pack pack = new Pack(msg.getSeq(), captureTime, srcIP, destIP, 
    msg.getPayloadLength(), msg.isSYN());

    (dataPkts.get(msg.getSeq())).add(pack);


}
```

Comment: what is `msg`? which error are you getting? where? have you debugged?

Comment: i did not debug because i know i initialized it wrongly..and msg is just a class in a library i am using and it is not the problem .. i use it to get a sequence number which is the Key to my hashmap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `List<Pack>` in your `HashMap`s are never defined. They are of the `interface` list but nowhere you identify what kind of `List` they are. You have to follow a structure as follows:

```
Map<long, List<Pack>> map = new HashMap<>() // java 7 syntax
List<Pack> packets = new ArrayList<>();
packets.add(pack);
map.put(msg.getAck(), packets);
```

When adding an element to the ´List´, which you now can because it exists, you do:

```
map.get(msg.getAck()).add(pack);
```

Comment: My pleasure, don't forget to accept the answer if it solved your problem and uovote if you deemed it a quality answer!

Answer (score 0):

You want to put `List` instances in first `Map`s before you use `add()` on them:

```
static List<Pack> datapktList = new ArrayList<Pack>();
static List<Pack> actpktList = new ArrayList<Pack>();
```

Then add respective `List` instance to `Map`:

```
ackPkts.put(msg.getAck(), datapktList );
dataPkts.put(msg.getAck(), actpktList );
```

Then following would work:

```
 (ackPkts.get(msg.getAck())).add(pack);
 (dataPkts.get(msg.getSeq())).add(pack);
```